# using delete / delete [] but still have memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I want to clean up the memory leaks from my code below. I cleaned it up and reduced it to it's simplest form. I keep getting memory leaks from valgrind. I want to use an array of objects to compile a list of names and than clean the memory so there are no leaks at the end. If at all possible, I'd like to declare the arrays in main.

```
//in Player.h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

class Player
{
    private:
        std::string first, last;

    public:

        Player();

        ~Player(); //I tried my code with and without this destructor

        Player(std::string first_name, std::string last_name);
    };

//in player.cpp

#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

Player::Player(std::string first_name, std::string last_name)
{
    this->first=first_name;
    this->last=last_name;
}

Player::~Player() 

{  //I tried both commands below separately and I still have memory leaks

    //delete [] Player; 
    //delete [] myPlayer;
}

// in Driver.cpp


#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    std::string temp_First, temp_Last;
    Player *myPlayer[2];

    temp_First="John";
    temp_Last="Smith";

    myPlayer[0] = new Player(temp_First, temp_Last);

    temp_First="Poca";
    temp_Last="Hontas";

    myPlayer[1] = new Player(temp_First, temp_Last);

    delete [] myPlayer; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not write code that requires using manual `delete` to begin with.

Comment: Std::vector would give what you need without the hassle of new/delete, so no memory leaks.

Comment: This will work perfectly fine with array of integer, double etc. But in the case of a object array some compiler does not support calling each destructor of objects in the array while your use delete []. Hence you have to call each destructor to release memory unfortunately.

Comment: @Abhijit That sounds wrong. Nobody would use such a compiler. Can you name one?

Comment: @Abhijit - not true.   The rule is that, for every usage of operator `new` to dynamically allocate objects, there needs to be a usage of the corresponding operator `delete` to release objects.   That's true whether the objects are a user-defined class or an `int`.    Dynamically allocating individual elements of an array requires releasing the individual elements of the array, not releasing the whole array.

Answer (score 4):

You need to free each element of `myPlayer` separately:

```
delete myPlayer[0];
delete myPlayer[1];
```

Since you have two calls to `new`, you need two corresponding `delete/delete[]` calls.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to use `new` / `delete` with your code at all?

A simple

```
 std::vector<Player> myPlayer;
```

would be sufficient.

Avoid to do dynamic memory management *hand rolled*, it's error prone and a consistent source of grief and trouble.

---

> If at all possible, I'd like to declare the arrays in main.

Here's a revised code:

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<Player> myPlayer {
        { "John", "Smith" } ,
        { "Poca", "Hontas"}
    };
    return 0;
}
```